# How to achive group call using easyrtc

Tags: node-webkit, easyrtc

I am new in easyrtc.

How can we achieve group call using easyrtc?
I know there are the createroom ,joinroom functions, but how exactly do they work?

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 0):

All thing you need are on client side not on server side
Here is very particular sample from easyRTC
https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc/blob/master/demos/demo_multiparty.html

You can refer server side on this project